# MyBatis - No constructor found

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a problem with MyBatis mapping.
I have a domain class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private Long id;
   private Date create;
   private String content;

   MyClass (Long id, Date create, String content)
   {
       this.id = id;
       this.create = create;
       this.content = content;
   }

   //getters and setters
```

A mapper class with a method like this:

```
   @Select("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id=#{id}")
   MyClass getMyClass (@Param("id") Long id);
```

In the database the three columns are of type Number, Timestamp and Clob and have the same name as in the class fields.

When I use this method I get a: 
*ExecutorException: No constructor found in [MyClass; matching [java.math.BigDecimal, java.sql.Timestamp, oracle.jdbc.OracleClob]*

But **if I remove the constructor from Myclass, then there is no problem at all**. I would like to have the constructor, how can I fix it?
I tried adding the @Results annotation in the mapper like so, but it didn't make any difference:

```
   @Results(value = {
      @Result(column = "id", property = "id", javaType = Long.class),
      @Result(column = "create", property = "create", javaType = Date.class),
      @Result(column = "content", property = "content", javaType = String.class)
   })
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MyBatis expects your model objects to have a no-arguments constructor (and possibly setters for each mapped field). Add those and everything should work.

Comment: This answer is no longer up to date. MyBatis supports Java Records, see [PR #2477](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/2477) and a [constructor definition in mappers](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#constructor) as specified in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `@ConstructorArgs` instead as follows:

```
@ConstructorArgs({
    @Arg(column = "id", javaType = Long.class)
    ,@Arg(column = "create", javaType = Date.class)
    ,@Arg(column = "content", javaType = String.class)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Mind that you need to add mybatis `@Param` annotation to the constructor in case you want to use `@ConstructorArgs`. So your constructor would look like:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private long id;
   private Date create;
   private String content;

   MyClass (@Param("id") long id, @Param("create") Date create, @Param("content") String content)
   {
       this.id = id;
       this.create = create;
       this.content = content;
   }
```

Then your mapper:

```
@ConstructorArgs({
   @Arg(name = "id", column = "id", javaType = long.class),
   @Arg(name = "create", column = "create", javaType = Date.class),
   @Arg(name = "content", column = "content", javaType = String.class)
})
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem: @Param annotations and the name argument in the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Just completing the answer of [@Kazuki Shimizu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39630778/3296947).

If you want to use the primitive type `long` instead of the wrapper `Long` in the constructor you need to change the binding to:

```
@ConstructorArgs({
   @Arg(column = "id", javaType = long.class)
   ,@Arg(column = "create", javaType = Date.class)
   ,@Arg(column = "content", javaType = String.class)
})
```